# How to make item stuck at bottom in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm looking for solution for hours and can't find anything which would be helpful for me to solve this problem.

What I have tried so far is using this library:
https://github.com/rubensousa/RecyclerViewSnap

However It didn't solve my problem because I need every item of recyclerview to be stuck at bottom. This is the mockup of the app how it should look:

[image]

And this is what I have created so far:

[image]

This first item will never be stuck at the bottom and I'm pretty out of idea what I should do next, so I would appreciate any help with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The RecyclerView size should be set to be smaller than match_parent otherwise you have items as far as it extends* therefore breaking one item being stuck at bottom. I can't figure what else you might be saying, but you can't stick one item to bottom using the RecyclerView as the RecyclerView must move. You can add another view in order to stick one item by loading that item into that other view. *If you want the RecyclerView scrolling to extend outside of the item then you need to set size of item view to be limited to area smaller than the RecyclerView block in the Activity/Frag,etc xml.

Comment: Hi @CmosBatterym, thanks for the answer. Let me just explain more. I need to have every item of recyclerview to be able to go through the bottom square which shows the current active channel.

Comment: You would still need to do what I said above. Either the RecycerView width and height needs to be smaller to be the size of an item stuck at the bottom or the item view used with the RecyclerView needs to force the rest of the RecyclerView to be empty so that only one item is visible at a time - though this will show an item scrolling through the entire display area of the app when scrolled. It still sounds to me like the former. Mind you, you still need something like RelativeLayout and layout_alignParentBottom=true, android:layout_alignParentLeft=true to have the view at the bottom left.